# Meteor Facebook Cordova Login not working

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, meteor

I have tried every combination of plugins to get it to work (currently testing on iOS).

The https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 facebook cordova plugin is successfully installed, but none of the Meteor plugins seem to do the trick.

For example, with https://atmospherejs.com/btafel/accounts-facebook-cordova, I get the error:

```
errorClass {stack: "errorClass@http://localhost:12592/packages/meteor.…       =27502404fad7fc072e57e8b0b6719f40d92709c7:1365:28", error: 400, reason:   "Unrecognized options for login request", details: undefined, message:  "Unrecognized options for login request [400]", …}
```

Login works perfectly on web.

Comment: Same issue here men... Let share the solution the first who find it.

Comment: Fixed it! It turns out that I had code in my Accounts.onCreateUser and Accounts.onLogin hooks that conflicted with the way that function sets up users. Once that was cleared up, it worked well. I also used the https://github.com/particles4dev-team/meteor-accounts-facebook-cordova package instead.

Comment: Nice.  I have it working now too... What I did was build the apk and the issue is not present anymore.  I did with mrt package following this instructions: https://gist.github.com/jamielob/881e0fe059c0ef0eb36d   When run on android-device the issue still appear.

Comment: @Ruben Hey, can you tell which meteor version you're using? Did you change anything while following the gist you linked to? Thanks.

Comment: @AbhishekBiswal I'm running meteor 1.3.1.   And yes, following the instructions in the link make it works for me.  Need to say that I'm using also crosswalk into my project and the only version of crosswalk compatible with that facebook plugin was the 1.4.